# Опережающее объявление typedef типа

Tags: c++, c, postgresql, libpq

Есть libpq, там есть объявление:

```
/* PGresult encapsulates the result of a query (or more precisely, of a single
 * SQL command --- a query string given to PQsendQuery can contain multiple
 * commands and thus return multiple PGresult objects).
 * The contents of this struct are not supposed to be known to applications.
 */
typedef struct pg_result PGresult;
```

Как правильно нужно использовать `PGresult` в опережающем объявлении (чтобы не тянуть заголовок libpq в .h файл)

```
struct pg_result; // собственно само опережающее объявление
typedef struct pg_result PGresult; // воссоздание типа PGresult
```

Как я понимаю это будет правильный вариант опережающего объявления, но нет ли тут каких-либо подводных камней?

Comment: Если typedef указать `void*` как значение, то ничего из заголовков подключать не придется, но есть и неприятные стороны. Это кастинг в функциях с этим типом, передача только ссылочным вариантом, и отсутствие контроля со стороны компилятора за передаваемым значением.

Comment: А зачем вам "двойное" обьявление? Или делайте typedef позже, или используйте `#define` макрос. Но если вы внимательно посмотрите на популярные библиотеки, то там, обьявляется структура, а ниже через typedef - ссылки на неё, т.е. возможно вы просто звёздочку пропустили (ссылку)? Всёравно компилятор не позволит использовать структуру напрямую до её полного обьявления, только посредством ссылки, поэтому нет смысла такой записи.

Comment: Вам нужно поменять местами строчки с #include так, что б на момент подключения  libpq структура pg_result  была уже обьявлена.

Comment: `typedef struct pg_result PGresult;` уже достаточно. Не нужно делать `struct pg_result;` перед этим. Не ясно только, зачем вам понадобилось "не тянуть заголовок libpq в .h файл".

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать также, как в libpq

> Есть libpq, там есть объявление:

```
/* PGresult encapsulates the result of a query (or more precisely, of a single
 * SQL command --- a query string given to PQsendQuery can contain multiple
 * commands and thus return multiple PGresult objects).
 * The contents of this struct are not supposed to be known to applications.
 */
 typedef struct pg_result PGresult;
```

Опережающее объявление сократит время сборки, так как компилятор не будет разбирать большие заголовки, следовательно компиляция может ускорится очень сильно.